# Are ignored / favorite tags both limited to 1400?

Tags: bug, tags, ignored-tags

Is there a limit for the number of tags a user can ignore / favorite? I've set a lot of ignore tags, but I'm still shown questions for tags which I have previously ignored. When I hover over such tags, I only see a silver star. I'm sure I have previosly set them to ignore (red cross) in the hover bubbles. By examining the HTML source of my preferences page, I see that I have exactly 1400 tags ignored.

This is very confusing because I got no notification of this and now some of my ignored tags are lost.

**Edit:** As for the off-topic question of why: When I joined I just started browsing through the new questions and favorited tags I'm interested in and ignored tags which are of no use to me (i.e. many javascript libraries, Microsoft stuff, Java stuff). Well there was a lot to ignore, especially because many questions have tags like visual-studio-2013_beta2 but not a visual-studio tag.

And I simply didn't know about the tag wildcard feature. Even if I knew, it is still easier to just ignore single tags on the questions page than go to user page -> preferences and manually enter the wildcard tag stuff.

Maybe the site needs a feature which automatically suggests to substitute tags like visual-studio-2013_beta2 visual-studio-2013_beta1 visual-studio-2012 etc with a single visual-studio* tag?

Comment: numbers would help...

Comment: You may not know that favorite and ignored tags support wildcards. Using some would probably lower your number of ignored tags by an order of magnitude or two.

Comment: There's almost certainly some kind of limit.

Comment: `$('#ignored-wrapper a.post-tag').length` indicates 1402, btw

Comment: Member for 14 days, ignoring 1400 tags. Are you sure you are in the right place?

Comment: @Jongware, member for 14 days, 742 rep, 6 questions (2 > +5), 25 answers (2 > +5), 23 points in the [c++] tag. Was able to blacklist more than 1400 tags in the aforementioned 14 days. I *hope* he's in the right place and we can count on him remaining part of this community in the future.

Comment: in case anyone else was wondering... the data explorer says there are 38,630 distinct tags.

Answer (score 13):

I'm actually amazed the site even works for you. Ignoring tags, with "Hide questions in your ignored tags" enabled (rather than "Gray out questions in your ignored tags") **isn't free**: the server needs to construct custom queries to filter out that data. Filtering out 1400 is... wow. We have previously tried to restrict the number of exclusions allowed, to avoid hurting system performance (and therefore impacting other users) - but it has caused a few problems whenever we've looked at it - mainly with users who do crazy things like ignore 1400 tags ;p Note that we *do* apply some hard limits both before and after wildcard expansion (with different numbers), but these are currently pretty high. I *can* say that beyond 5 (yes, just 5) tags, the server disables things like retries - if your expensive query fails once: tough.

I am *not* aware of a specific limit in terms of preventing you adding more ignored tags; I will investigate - but I'm very very curious why you would choose to cull 1400 tags... what usage scenario is it that you are trying to achieve here? (there may be better ways to do it...)

Comment: I think the usage scenario here is that the OP only wants to see certain tags on the front page, and hide everything else.

Comment: @Stijn exactly; if *that* is what the OP wants: *there are better ways to do that* - for example [here's my bookmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+.net+or+protobuf-net+or+protocol-buffers+or+dapper+or+stackexchange.redis); a new option like `/questions/my-favorites` would be viable, as a more flexible alternative (url not fixed)

Comment: @iStimple whether it is done client-side of server-side depends on the exact page; there are definitely places where this happens server-side

Comment: I thought the filtering was client-side because the bug listings (e.g. on the "questions" -> "newest" or "unanswered" -> "newest" pages) were first loaded (and displayed for a split of second) by the browser and then the ignored tags filtering kicked in and hid all the questions with ignored tags. Sometimes all questions were hidden (0 questions on page).

Comment: @jotik depends on the page