# A section to view all questions in the same screen from your favorite tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-watching

To view questions from your favorite tags, you have to click on each individual tag. Wouldn't it be better to select the favorite tags and then have them all appear in the screen i-e home screen.

Is there anything on here like this? if not what you are thoughts?

Comment: Supporting this - Maybe just another "Pseudo-Tag" called "All-My-Tags".

Comment: You can search for multiple tags; for example, `[c] or [png]`. Then bookmark it. (I wonder how long the search string can be. It may be a problem for our one [1,400 Tags User](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269168/are-ignored-favorite-tags-both-limited-to-1400).)

Comment: Yes exactly, because it would be much easier to see questions you are interested in@dognose

Comment: yea having a tag or a section specifically, saves you know bookmarking it etc. But it's worth a shot!

Comment: As Jongware mentioned you can observe new questions from few tags by manually typing `[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3]` in [searchbox](http://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: You can use wildcards, to easen things. For Android related questions I use `*ndro*`. I also use this kind of filter not to see unwanted posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do a search. Type `intags:mine` or `intags:me` in the search box to find all posts in one of your favorite tags.

You can combine this with other search terms. For example, to only see questions with one of your favorite tags, use:

```
intags:mine is:question
```

Comment: If this is so simple, than it's also simple to implement. Personally, since my eye is so accustomed to the way the home-screen presents questions, I find the search results very uncomfortable to follow.

Comment: I totally agree, if its already in place in a way. Surely it can be implemented in a way which makes it easier to view the tags all in one place.

Comment: @Korem totally agree. I've been on SO for years and now I kinda *need* the way the home screen looks. I've been using Dason's solution all that time, which means once in a while bookmarks need updating across all machines I use. I whish there was just stackoverflow.com/questions/taggedlike/mine or so.

Answer (score 4):

Along with @Reto's answer you can do this manually just by searching for your tags.  For instance I have the r, rstudio, and knitr tags favorited so I can do a search with the query

```
[r] or [rstudio] or [knitr]
```

I actually have this bookmarked.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r%20or%20rstudio%20or%20knitr